# SQL Query in MS Access returning different results every so often

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have this query which feeds into a report. Yesterday, I ran the report and it only returned 8 results instead of ~200 records. I removed the inner join and the person_ID column and it started working again. Today, I ran the report with the original query and it is working again. This is a MS Access front end with a SQL Server backend. Can anyone tell me what happened?

```
SELECT DISTINCT qryNumPiActiveProjectsFiltered.[Child Department] AS Department, 
   Max(qryNumPiActiveProjectsFiltered.[Child PI S Name]) AS [PI Name], 
   Max(qryPiMeetingQuarter.Author) AS Author, 
   Max(qryNumPiActiveProjectsFiltered.[Child SPFMS Initials]) AS [SPA Rep], 
   qryNumPiActiveProjectsFiltered.NumOfAccounts, 
   Max(qryPiMeetingQuarter.Contact_Date) AS [Most Recent Meeting], 
   Max(IIf([Contact_Date] Is Null,Null,[Contact_Date]+91)) AS [Next 1 Meeting], 
   Max(IIf([Contact_Date] Is Null,Null,[Contact_Date]+182)) AS [Next 2 Meeting], 
   Max(IIf([Contact_Date] Is Null,Null,[Contact_Date]+273)) AS [Next 3 Meeting], 
   Max(qryNumPiActiveProjectsFiltered.[Child Department] & "-" & dbo_ff.[Child Pi Id]) AS Person_ID    
FROM ((qryNumPiActiveProjectsFiltered 
   LEFT JOIN tblPerson ON qryNumPiActiveProjectsFiltered.[Child PI S Name] = tblPerson.Person_name) 
   LEFT JOIN qryPiMeetingQuarter ON tblPerson.Person_id = qryPiMeetingQuarter.Person_id) 
   INNER JOIN dbo_ff ON qryNumPiActiveProjectsFiltered.[Child PI S Name] = dbo_ff.[Child PI S Name]    
GROUP BY qryNumPiActiveProjectsFiltered.[Child Department], 
   qryNumPiActiveProjectsFiltered.NumOfAccounts
ORDER BY qryNumPiActiveProjectsFiltered.NumOfAccounts DESC;
```

Edit: I just wanted to clarify some things. The query is for a report showing meeting dates for 2nd quarter of this year. It should not be changing that much, the only thing that should change is the data in the records not the number of records. I also wanted to clarify what is happening, I ran the same query and it's now returning the correct amount of records (~200). To clarify, I added in the inner join and the Person_ID, the report still returned ~200 records. The next day the same query only returns 8 records. The day after that the same query returned 200 again

Comment: I'm guessing there are only 8 records where qryNumPiActiveProjectsFiltered.[Child PI S Name] = dbo_ff.[Child PI S Name]

Comment: But I ran the same query and it's now returning the correct amount of records (~200). To clarify, I added in the inner join and the Person_ID, the report still returned ~200 records. The next day the same query only returns 8 records. The day after that the same query returned 200 again.

Comment: If it returned the same data every day you ran it, you'd have a pretty worthless query.

Comment: @nicomp Sorry that I was not clear in my original question. This is a query that feeds a report. Please see my edits to my question.

Comment: @JackRussel My comment stands. A query, even if it feeds a report, is pretty worthless if it returns the same thing every time you run it. My point is that the underlying data changes and perhaps that is why you get the results you get.

Comment: What is `qryNumPiActiveProjectsFiltered`?    Is it a static table, or is it a function or some other kind of stored query?

Comment: @JackRussel it's pretty hard to decipher your query without knowing what goes into each table and each column. Like nicomp said, your best bet is to check what changed in your tables, and which intersections might have cut down the results to 8. Personally I'd look at the INNER JOIN and GROUP BY, everything else doesn't seem like it'd shrink down results.

Comment: Also, keep in mind how your Access / SQL is set up regarding dates. I saw Contact_Date, and yesterday was 12/10/2017 in PT, which depending on locale settings can be interpreted as 12th day of 10th month, or 10th day of 12th month. Which would be 2 months ahead, and might return less meeting dates (supposing most meetings are in the next 2 months).